timedatectl shows "NTP synchronized: no" even though chrony seems synced
I am trying to use the timedatectl status to determine if the time is synced or not across several hundred devices. Most use ntpd, but I switched a few to chrony because of issues with ntpd, and chrony seems to be more reliable.
One of these devices alternates between synchronized and not synchronized (according to timedatectl) throughout the day. But when I check, as far as I can tell, chrony is synced.
$ chronyc sources
210 Number of sources = 4
MS Name/IP address         Stratum Poll Reach LastRx Last sample
===============================================================================
^+ 44.190.5.123                  2  10   377   123   +847us[ +847us] +/-   37ms
^+ ns2.fortrockdc.com            2  10   377    49  +2591us[+2591us] +/-   45ms
^* dutch.arpnet.net              2  10   377   686  +1809us[+2645us] +/-   28ms
^- spidey.rellim.com             2  10   377   544  +4326us[+4326us] +/-   64ms

$ chronyc tracking
Reference ID    : 168.235.89.132 (dutch.arpnet.net)
Stratum         : 3
Ref time (UTC)  : Tue Jul 23 13:32:27 2024
System time     : 0.000968409 seconds fast of NTP time
Last offset     : +0.000836225 seconds
RMS offset      : 0.000711596 seconds
Frequency       : 51.080 ppm fast
Residual freq   : +0.099 ppm
Skew            : 0.220 ppm
Root delay      : 0.019650 seconds
Root dispersion : 0.012654 seconds
Update interval : 1027.8 seconds
Leap status     : Normal

timedatectl reports that ntp is not synchronized:
$ timedatectl status
      Local time: Tue 2024-07-23 08:42:20 EST
  Universal time: Tue 2024-07-23 13:42:20 UTC
        RTC time: Sat 2003-07-26 20:17:35
       Time zone: SystemV/EST5 (EST, -0500)
     NTP enabled: yes
NTP synchronized: no
 RTC in local TZ: no
      DST active: n/a

I can run chronyc -a makestep and this will flip the timedatectl status for a time.
How can I figure out why the timedatectl status is reporting not synchronized sometimes?

Is there something about the sources or tracking that I don't understand? Or something else I need to check?
Or do I need to find a different way to monitor the synchronization status?

System

Device: TI AM335x BeagleBone
Debian 8.11 Jessie
chrony 1.30


timedatectl might have to informed that a ntp client had been installed on the system to properly report ntp status (with timedatectl set-ntp true) or an override might be required like explained in example two of https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/latest/systemd-timedated.service.html to make it aware of chrony

You can see that it has already been run where it the status says NTP enabled: yes. I'll try the override you suggest, thanks.
